# Can I load a file from a bundled javascript application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, gulp

I have a node application that when built is bundled all into one file. I want to split out of this bundle the app configuration parameters (it's just a simple object).

The `./build` directory becomes populated with only three files: `index.js`, `config.js` and a map file.

When I `cd` into the directory and launch the app with `node index.js`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logPath' of undefined
    at Module.<anonymous> (/home/*/repo/build/index.js:1:2367)
    at t (/home/*/repo/build/index.js:1:172)
    at /home/*/repo/build/index.js:1:964
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/*/repo/build/index.js:1:973)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

The top of the built `config.js` file looks like

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.config = {
    logPath: 'logs',
    ....
};
```

The webpack configuration I am using looks as such

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

function excludeConfig(context, request, callback) {
    /config/.test(request)
        ? callback(null, 'require("./config.js")', + request)
        : callback();
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/server/index.js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: ['node_modules']
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                enforce: 'pre'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/build')
    },
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [
        nodeExternals(),
        excludeConfig
    ],
};
```

My config file is being built by *gulp* with the following strategy

```
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('add-config', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('src/*config.ts')
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

The `tsconfig.json` file looks as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    }
}
```

My hunch is that after the build the configuration file is not providing what the bundle is expecting.

The bundle does contain the following line:

```
function (e, r) { e.exports = require("./config.js") }
```

Any ideas on how I can make the bundle load the `config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after much static analysis, and lack of a comprehensive understanding of the different ways to import modules, for some reason the bundle defines my config file to be a harmony import and attempts to retrieve a `default` from the file (which in my case I hadn't any).

There are two fixes available (both worked fine):

- change the import style away from using defaults by using brackets around the import (I don't know why I prefer this)

```
import { config } from './../../config';
```

- change the export style and adopt the default route

```
export default <Config>{
    logPath: 'logs',
    ...
};
```

To be honest, I don't know why this worked before when this project had still not started the migration to TypeScript. I know that everything *babel* related was removed before I started so I can't get my head around it.

#### Webpack Internals

The module loader looks like this:

```
(function(module, exports) {
    module.exports = require("./config.js");
})
```

It is then passed on to another module and loaded as follows:

```
/* harmony import */ var _config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./../../config */ "./../config");
/* harmony import */ var _config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
const PATH = _config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.logPath.replace(/\/*$/, '');
```

Notice how `_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__` already has the contents of my configuration object. However, webpack sends it into a function `n` which encapsulates the import into a getter function on member `a`. This encapsulation resolves to using `default` if the module was marked as an `esModule`

```
__webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
    var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
        function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
        function getModuleExports() { return module; };
    __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
    return getter;
};
```